# HDD bad sectors with OS

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ext4, bad-sectors

**I wonder is that possible for OS to make bad sectors on Hard Drive?**

*Preface:*

I have bought new HDD on 1Tb WB Caviar Black. I have installed new OS on **ext4** partition **Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS**. After few days **S.M.A.R.T.** of the Ubuntu's Disk Utility show that my hard has bad sectors! I have checked on **S.M.A.R.T.** immediately after installing OS - all was OK. During new OS working I have noticed some strange with HDD - all OS was freezed from 20 sec to 1 min and I have heard like HDD's engine restarting. At the **dmes** I have found something like this:

```
[40085.407947] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
```

Comment: No, Its not possible for software to create bad sectors, the hardware itself is starting to fail.  You could press you luck, live with the current bad sectors, and it likely will not get any worse.  Of course it also could get worse.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with bad hard drives goes back into the late 1990's. You would do best to get the bootable version of Data Lifeguard Diagnostic, available here:

http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=613&sid=30&lang=en

You will find the basic info on how to create the needed CD. Boot from it and check your disk with the 'Quick Test' and if it passes that, run the 'Extended Test'. If it fails either test, you should start the RMA process with WDC.com here:

http://support.wdc.com/warranty/index.asp?wdc_lang=en

I suspect your drive is toast as the error message indicates the literal boot sector has failed.

Good luck.

Comment: OK, thanks! But what will you say about disk engine restart? Could it be due to not enough watts from Power Supply? I have 350W and I have calculated here http://support.asus.com/PowerSupply.aspx?SLanguage=en it seems for my system 300W is enough. What are you think regarding this?

Comment: Yes. It must be power supply. Check with different stronger PSU.